# How can I return the login URL for a DotNetNuke site if my current Session hasn't registered with DNN?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

So I have a little helper method that will return the login URL for the DotNetNuke site but it only works if you have the (PortalSettings and HttpRequest objects).

Unfortunately, calling on the DNN static method:

```
PortalController.GetCurrentPortalSettings
```

Doesn't return the PortalSettings object if my session hasn't registered with DNN.  My situation is that I have a ajax calls to a web method that I would like to retrieve the login url and return the string to the page in order to redirect a user to the login page who's session timed out.

Unfortunately, it return's null.

```
Message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: portalSettings","StackTrace":"
```

The PortalController method is returning null.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding portalId as a querystring parameter in your AJAX request (i.e instead of `/DesktopModules/MyModule/Service.asmx` use `/DesktopModules/MyModules/Service.asmx?portalId=1`).  This should let DNN process the request enough to create a `PortalSettings` object.